# Simplest way to define an edge attribute for all edges in NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, attributes, networkx

I am wondering if there is a **simpler way to define an edge attribute for all edges** in NetworkX, other than doing it individually for each edge such as:

```py
import networkx as nx
#Number of vertices
N = 20
G=nx.complete_graph(N)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i):
            G.edges[i, j]['weight'] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values = 1, name = 'weight')
```